# Magento - Create an Attribute Similar to Tier Pricing

Tags: magento

I am trying to create an attribute that works like the tier pricing on the admin side. Essentially, we want the ability to show the current price of the product and offer specific discount % on a product based on the total dollar amount in the cart. (the product price would change as cart total changes)

Example:

- If cart total is between $1-$999.99, product discount is 5%
- If cart total is between $1,000-$5,000 product price is discounted 10%

and so on... (I have a screenshot of what we are looking to accomplish, but can't post it yet...)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I believe you can accomplish this using cart rules. Its in the admin under Promotions > Shopping Cart Rules

Comment: Thanks for the response russjman, but the part I am having issues with is displaying the price of the item on the product page based on the current cart value. Does that make sense? Thanks again.